# What is a word that means 'things that have been seen'?

Tags: terminology

I need a word that means 'things that have been seen'.  I'd be happy with a made-up or foreign word, if the meaning is relatively clear to English speakers.

For example, using the word 'floop' for now, I would want to be able to say things like: "In the context of movies, my floops include Die Hard, but not Die Hard 4".  Or "My floops yesterday included a bald cat".

Comment: It simply depends on the exact sentence/topic at hand. There is no one word. Note that "seeing" a cat (literally, you glanced at it, you "looked at it with your eyes") is an utterly different concept from "I read a book" or "I watched a DVD" or "I went to a movie." It's just a coincidence that the word "see" is used as an alternative to "watching"/"viewing" a movie.  WS has given your two specific solutions below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious answer seems to be **'sightings'**.

It would work for the bald-cat example, but perhaps not for the movies.

That would be **'viewings**.

Comment: Hmm, I don't really have any better suggestions, but both of those (and in particular the _viewings_ one) sound a bit clunky in the OP's example sentences. (On the other hand, if the OP is happy with a made-up or foreign word, maybe that's not an issue)

Comment: The key point is there's simply no one solution. The OP has accidentally conflated two utterly different senses of "see".

Comment: I think 'viewings' works best for what I want (naming a table in a database).  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If FaceBook can turn "likes" into a noun, there's no reason you can't use "sees", for example:

> ***I count "Die Hard", a bald cat and my best friend's chartreuse Karmann Ghia among my favorite "sees" today!***

Comment: @medica You could even write a list of your favourite 'Seven sees'!

Comment: @WS2 - I like that idea! It's like a short 'bucket list'. Kristina, I wish this would catch on.

Answer (score -1):

Please consider the following: encounters, experiences, perceptions, visions, memories, images, and hallucinations.  "Objects" doesn't include all of the "'things that have been seen'" by James Taylor, i.e. "lonely times."
Heinlein's Stranger's word might be grokked as a noun, but then one of your groks includes a bald cat.